# What does this 'wanted' ad mean?

Tags: cryptic-clues

I saw this ad in the 'wanted' section of the classifieds:

> Male seeks precious stone (only hollow).
>   Call Antonio: 018 911 937

I thought it was fairly innocent, but a friend told me it was actually a warning against something malevolent. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I thought I was onto something on this one but then I saw it was "cryptic clues" and I'm garbage at figuring those out

Comment: Well I'm no expert on cryptic clues, I've never done cryptic crosswords myself and certainly never created a cryptic clue before, so it might not be strictly cryptic (if there is such a thing). Should be solvable though :)

Comment: I'd say you did a good job!

Comment: Out of curiosity - is 3 sets of 3 digits a common phone number format anywhere in the world?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Scanning [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers), it appears that Portugal and Spain do that (though not starting with a 0), maybe others.

Comment: @question_asker: I see Peru as well, apparently.  No English-speaking countries, though, so there's likely nowhere this puzzle would work and also be a valid phone number...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it could be a valid phone number that connects you in the first n (less than 9) digits. e.g., 018 connects to some place or area code, 911 connects to 911 there, and 937 gets ignored.

Comment: Just call and ask.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## NOW IN ANSWER FORM

Antonio

> Gramsci lived from 1891 to 1937... perhaps we're being warned about [hegemony](http://www.marxists.org/glossary/terms/h/e.htm)?
>
>  'Male' = *he*
>  'precious stone' = *gem*
>  'only hollow' = on<s>l</s>y = *ony*
>
>
>
>   <sub>I'm throwing a little party for myself for being able to link to marxists dot org in an answer</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I haven't got the true meaning, but can see a hint of malevolence:

> **Call** <s>Antonio: 018</s> **911** <s>937</s>

Comment: but i am not sure why it would be on classifieds...o_O

Comment: @manshu maybe it's like, a really chill emergency.

Comment: @question_asker like robbers are at home but you baked some teeth-breaking cookies for them, and its taking time to eat them now. That kind of chill?

Comment: @manshu that's precisely it, manshu. you've done it again

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ad published in the UK, it should bloody well be a UK phone number. 01891 (or rather, 0891) was once used for BT ValueCall Premium rate numbers according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialling_codes_in_the_United_Kingdom , so the strange formatting might be intended to obfuscate that fact. I've seen the same sort of game in German 0900 premium numbers.